# Weird linq-to-sql error

Tags: .net, linq-to-sql

the error happens in this line:

```
OldPerson.PersonSerial = context.DB.Persons.Max(Function(p) p.PersonSerial) + 1
```

> Could not find key member 'ID' of key
>   'ID' on type 'Nationality'. The key
>   may be wrong or the field or property
>   on 'Nationality' has changed names.

there's a person table containing a foreign key to the nationality table.
i checked up that the column names match

what might be the cause of this error?

Comment: Is there a base-class in the mix here? http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/480761/linq-to-sql-xml-mapping-association-key-to-different-member-name-than-column-name-throws-invalidoperationexception

Comment: yes both person and nationality inherit a base class

Comment: @Marc Gravell:man how did you figure it out on the fly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

looks like sharing a base class for partial linq generated classes is causing this issue.

i removed the inheritance from the base class and it worked. No idea why though!

Comment: The scenario is not supported.